# How to cache images and label texts downloaded from the internet for every uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, uitableview, nscache

I download texts and image for every table cell from internet. I do it in background (GCD), but performance is not good (takes a while to dll images for all rows) because there are lots of rows.

I use nsurlconnection for image dll.

I googled a bit and became confused. What is the easiest way to do this?
Use NSCache (for images and text) or do i have to learn core data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout `https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/` for a super simple way of doing this...

From the README:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

This is all you need for cached images.  You can look at the source for how to extend this to support caching text objects too.  Alternatively you could use `NSUserDefaults` to store Key-Value pairs based on URL and text data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/) to download & cache images.

Comment: i'm also using SDWebImage or AFNetworking's UIImageView class right now :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using blocks and [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for that and it works fine.

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:<yoururl>]];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy];


[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    //do your things
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^{
     //request failed - inform the user
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: I would like to use existing code for data download (nsurlconnection).

Comment: You will be amazed by the advantages of ASIHTTPRequest ;) half of the world uses it ...

Answer (score 1):

i use this lib to cashe web images
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage 
very simple to use 

`[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yoururl]];`